# Multiply-nested IIF Statements Returning SSRS Error

Tags: reporting-services

I’m using SSRS 2014 & getting an error with multiple nested IIF statements.  Probably I’m totally wrong about my approach to this, but I thought I could nest a condition/DWT/DWF triplet in place of either a DWT or DWF in another condition.  This isn’t working out for me.

Basically, I’m trying to color code report rows based upon meeting certain conditions.  In short, some districts are being singled out depending upon the number of days they haven’t worked a project.

I’ve twisted this expression like a rubic’s cube.  I’m sure I’m just missing something obvious, but at this point, I’ve been diddling with it on and off for hours, changing syntactical elements, the order of things, etc., and all I get from SSRS is an unhelpful complaint about a missing right parenthesis.

Here’s the latest iteration:

```
=iif(Fields!District.Value="999","LightGreen",
 iif(Max(Fields!DaysUnworked.Value) >60,"LightCoral",
 iif(Max(Fields! DaysUnworked.Value) >=45,"Khaki",
 iif(Fields!District.Value="50"
     OR Fields! District.Value="35"
     OR Fields! District.Value= "25"
     OR Fields! District.Value="19"
     OR Fields! District.Value="7","LimeGreen",
 iif(Max(Fields!DaysUnworked.Value) >60,"LightCoral",
 iif(Max(Fields!DaysUnworked.Value) >=30,"Khaki",                                  
 iif(Max(Fields!DaysUnworked.Value<30,"LightGreen","Transparent"))))
```

The idea here is that all districts except those specifically mentioned by number will be shaded “LimeGreen”.

One district (999) will be shaded a different color based upon days unworked, and in its case, it’ll be under 45 days is “LightGreen”, between 45 (inclusive) & 60 will be “Khaki” and over 60 will be “LightCoral”.

The other specifically named districts will be similar to the above, but instead of <45, >=45, >60, they will use <30, >=30, >60.

SSRS is not barfing on anything I try except either “)” or “,” or both.

I know, I know, the coloration is kinda silly...but I just do what I’m told (or try to, anyway).

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I’m guessing this is going to turn out to be really simple & I’ll feel super dumb later.  (Won’t be the first time, though).  Thanks in advance, you the greatest, y’all.

Comment: I think the last line of the code block got cut off.  I’m using an ipad for this, so maybe that’s why.  Just in case, here is the last line:
                 iif(Max(Fields!DaysUnworked.Value) <30,"LightGreen","Transparent"))))

Comment: You can always edit your question to fix it. The last line was missing the four-space prefix that indicates code and got pushed off to the right, fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the "switch" function maybe a little easier:

```
=switch(Fields!District.Value="999","LightGreen",
        Max(Fields!DaysUnworked.Value) >60,"LightCoral",
        Max(Fields! DaysUnworked.Value) >=45,"Khaki",
        Fields!District.Value="50","LimeGreen",
        Fields! District.Value="35","LimeGreen",
        Fields! District.Value= "25","LimeGreen",
        Fields! District.Value="19","LimeGreen",
        Fields! District.Value="7","LimeGreen",
        Max(Fields!DaysUnworked.Value) >60,"LightCoral",
        Max(Fields!DaysUnworked.Value) >=30,"Khaki",                                  
        Max(Fields!DaysUnworked.Value) <30,"LightGreen")
```

Comment: +1. Switch is much better for this than IIF. A slight improvement, given that everything that isn't specifically mentioned should be LimeGreen, would be to remove the LimeGreen conditionals and have a final line with `True, "LimeGreen"`. That way anything not caught in a conditional above will fall through to LimeGreen and any new districts will automatically be coloured LimeGreen without having to add a new conditional.

Answer (score 0):

I see a simpler way to handle this, as a good chunk of the values are going to be lime green, is to set everything that doesn't match the different values to lime green.  Additionally, there does seem to be some syntactical errors.  The main thing I see is spaces in some of the Field declarations.  It should be `Fields!District.Value` with no spaces.  Here's how I'd simplify this expression.

```
=IIF(Fields!District.Value="999" OR MAX(Fields!DaysUnworked.Value < 30),"LightGreen",
    IIF(Max(Fields!DaysUnworked.Value)>=30,"Khaki",
        IIF(Max(Fields!DaysUnworked.Value)>60, "LightCoral", "LimeGreen")))
```

While looking at this, I noticed you have two comparisons for `DaysUnworked` -- one for `>=30` and another for `>=45`.  You should be able to capture all of those with a single expression. You also had two different comparisons for `DaysUnworked > 60`. This expression should cover everything.